# How to troubleshoot problems with Vue Router/params?

Tags: vue.js

I am working with VueJs 2, and I am trying to get routing to work, so bassically if I go to URL/test/5, the ID will equal 5 and then for now, the component should simply display 5 on the main page.

Right now this is what my routes.js file looks like:

```js
import test from '@/components/test_token'
import Home from '@/views/Home'


export default[    
{
           
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
},

{
    path: '/test/:id',
    component: test_token
  
}
]
```

This is what test_token.vue looks like:

```html
<template>
    
    <div>User {{ $route.params.id }}</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
        name: 'test_token',
  data() {
    return {
    
        id: this.$route.params.id
     
    };
  },

}
</script>
```

And this is what my main.js file is looking like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Routes from './routes'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)



const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: Routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
el: '#app',
render: h => h(App),
router: router
})
```

What I am having trouble with is I have no idea how to trouble shoot this problem, because when I go to the page url/test/10, for example, it is just a completely blank page that displays nothing. ALso I am currently on vue version 2.7.10 and vue router 3.5.4.

My desired result is to see something like this when I go to url/test/10:

```html
  <div>User 10</div>
```

Comment: Want to troubleshoot? Vue devtools, `routes` tab. You'll see what is available, what is active, the given params etc.

Comment: Also, it should probably be `component: test` in your `routes.js` file (since it's the name you're importing `test_token` with). Check a console error, there is probably something down there too.